# model passed as null to the post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, model-binding

First of all, I tried all the solutions that I came across after searching online but nothing worked. My idea is to search by user id and the result is two checkbox lists of permissions and departments. By default, the checkbox is checked in the tables if the user has access to it. The problem is the model passed from the view to the post method is null. So if I tried to select or change anything and clicked save, the model doesn't have any values from the post. What am I doing wrong? How do I correct it?

my viewmodel:

```
    public class MainViewModel
    {        
        public int SearchId { get; set; }
        public List<UserPermissionViewModel> UserPermissions { get; set; }
        public List<UserDepartmentViewModel> UserDepartments { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserDepartmentViewModel
    {
        public int DepId { get; set; }
        public string DepName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserPermissionViewModel
    {
        public int PerId { get; set; }
        public string PerName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked_ { get; set; }
    }
```

my post method at controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SaveData (MainViewModel model)
        {
            //remove existing user from the table in db
            db.TBL_UserPermissions
            .RemoveRange(db.TBL_UserPermissions
            .Where(x => x.UserID == model.SearchId));

            db.TBL_User_Dep_Access
              .RemoveRange(db.TBL_User_Dep_Access
              .Where(x => x.UserID == model.SearchId));

            //adding what is selected from the checkboxes to the table in the db
            foreach (var dep in model.UserDepartments)
            {
                if (dep.IsChecked)
                {
                    TBL_User_Dep_Access tBL_User_Dep_ = new TBL_User_Dep_Access();
                    tBL_User_Dep_.UserID = model.SearchId;
                    tBL_User_Dep_.Dep_ID = dep.DepId;
                    tBL_User_Dep_.IsActive = true;
                    db.TBL_User_Dep_Access.Add(tBL_User_Dep_);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            //adding what is selected from the checkboxes to the table in the db
            foreach (var per in model.UserPermissions)
            {
                if (per.IsChecked_)
                {
                    TBL_UserPermissions tBL_UserPermissions = new TBL_UserPermissions();
                    tBL_UserPermissions.UserID = model.SearchId;
                    tBL_UserPermissions.PermissionID = per.PerId;
                    tBL_UserPermissions.IsActive = true;
                    db.TBL_UserPermissions.Add(tBL_UserPermissions);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Get method :

```
     public ActionResult Index(int?SearchId)
        {
            var model = new MainViewModel();
            var usr_Dep = db.TBL_User_Dep_Access
              .Where(x => x.UserID == SearchId)
              .Select(x => x.Dep_ID)
              .ToList();

            var usr_Per = db.TBL_UserPermissions
               .Where(x => x.UserID == SearchId)
               .Select(x => x.PermissionID)
               .ToList();

            if (SearchId != null)
            {
                List<UserDepartmentViewModel> Udep 
                        = db.TBL_Department.Select(i =>
                new UserDepartmentViewModel
                {
                    DepId = i.Department_ID,
                    DepName = i.Department_Name,
                    IsChecked = usr_Dep.Contains(i.Department_ID)
                }).ToList();

                List<UserPermissionViewModel> Uper 
                        = db.TBL_Permissions.Select(i =>
                 new UserPermissionViewModel
                {
                    PerId = i.PermissionID,
                    PerName = i.PermissionName,
                    IsChecked_ = usr_Per.Contains(i.PermissionID)

                }).ToList();

                model.UserDepartments = Udep;
                model.UserPermissions = Uper;

            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

my view

```
@model Staff_Req.Models.MainViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Access"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("SearchId", "", new { @id = "SearchId", @placeholder = "Search for...", @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Search" type="submit">Go! />
    </span>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Access", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="hidden" name="model.SearchId" id="SaveData_SearchId" />
    <ul>
        @if (Model.UserDepartments != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserDepartments.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.UserDepartments[i].IsChecked)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.UserDepartments[i].DepName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.UserDepartments[i].DepId)
            }
        }

    </ul>
    <ul>
        @if (Model.UserPermissions != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserPermissions.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.UserPermissions[i].IsChecked_)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.UserPermissions[i].PerName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.UserPermissions[i].PerId)
            }
        }

    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}


@section Scripts {
        <script>
            $("#saveForm").submit(function () {
                $("#SaveData_SearchId").val($("#SearchId").val());
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Does this help ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548991/how-can-i-pass-complex-object-from-view-to-controller-with-post-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Can you post the JSON which you are sending to the post method?

Comment: Call this function by using a postman? If the issue still exists, paste that JSON here.

Comment: I'm not using any JSON to post the function. why would i use it ?

Comment: could you elaborate on how to call it by using a postman?

Comment: @panoskarajohn my code follows all the instructions that the other user wasn't and still .the model null. I'm new to MVC, do you think my logic isn't correct or this is poor programming from my side?

Comment: Also listen to the comments, what they tell you? Most of the times it is not poor coding skills, you need to know your tools. When you click the submit button, in the network tab, you can see what data is passed. Postman is an excellent tool to test your WEB APIS. To conclude, if you want answers you need to rewrite your `get method`, so we will be able to reproduce the problem. Instead of a db call return a manually filled `List`. `I think yout issue is that you pass a List to the controller try sth like this public ActionResult SaveData (List<MainViewModel> model)`.

Comment: it broke a lot of errors. if I did it as a list do I have to change my ViewModel?

Comment: as any line in the code with model.something is an error now.

Comment: Please check with `FormCollection` may be you got the right point what you missed in the action.

Comment: hey, @panoskarajohn I downloaded the postman. but it is a tool for testing web API application and my application is web application MVC. have any idea of testing my get and post functions ??

Comment: I am not sure either, you should be able to pass json to the post. It should work the same as a web api...Did you manage to resolve your issue though?

Comment: no @panoskarajohn. my model still passes to the post method as null . and i have no idea where is the issue .i would appreciate if you have an idea for me to implement even if if it was adding another function or view .

Comment: Could you please refactor your get method to use `custom created lists`? If you refactor i will debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a simple fix.  I think what is happening is your SearchId is confusing the modelBinder.

When I copied your code, did a post and looked at the network tab under form data I saw this:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: T2O4PFE3MRyyVfj1nnnCTV2P6zgGe8-OPFXSvQTeU8fLI07zkQZk1vsKAKf6pzbLl0Df4Cd3VnT3C0XjmLeLWgaRcdXBY6BiXCWQjKjYuqw1
model.SearchId: 1
UserDepartments[0].IsChecked: true
UserDepartments[0].IsChecked: false
UserDepartments[0].DepId: 1
UserDepartments[1].IsChecked: true
UserDepartments[1].IsChecked: false
UserDepartments[1].DepId: 2
UserDepartments[2].IsChecked: false
UserDepartments[2].DepId: 3
UserPermissions[0].IsChecked_: true
UserPermissions[0].IsChecked_: false
UserPermissions[0].PerId: 1
UserPermissions[1].IsChecked_: true
UserPermissions[1].IsChecked_: false
UserPermissions[1].PerId: 2
UserPermissions[2].IsChecked_: false
UserPermissions[2].PerId: 3
```

It looks like this makes the model binder think everything is going to start with model. because SearchId does.

So to solve in your view change

```
<input type="hidden" name="model.SearchId" id="SaveData_SearchId" />
```

to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="SearchId" id="SaveData_SearchId" />
```

I.e. remove model.

Then it should work fine.

Comment: I wanted to ask . have you used postman for post request testing.

Comment: Yes I have done on several occasions.   Postman is useful for testing how your server responds to requests made to it.  As it turns out it wouldn't have helped you here because the problem was that your form was sending the wrong information to the server.  So in this instance what was needed was the developer tools in the browser to see what your form was actually sending.  I used the network tab in Chrome and double clicked on the post after it was made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your post data with a [FromBody] attribute:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SaveData ([FromBody]MainViewModel model)
{
   ...
```

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. still, null .the only thing that with value is the searchId .

Answer (score 0):

I have ran your code. And I see model is retaining the values in post call. you need to make below changes in view file.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SearchId)
<ul>
    @if (Model?.UserDepartments != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserDepartments.Count(); i++)
        {

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserDepartments[i].IsChecked)
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserDepartments[i].DepName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserDepartments[i].DepId)
        }
    }

</ul>


<ul>
    @if (Model?.UserPermissions != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserPermissions.Count(); i++)
        {

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserPermissions[i].IsChecked_)
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserPermissions[i].PerName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserPermissions[i].PerId)
        }
    }

</ul>


<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: I wanted a list of checkboxes so I think i don't need @html.editorfor()

Comment: your checkbox value will not be retained without EditorFor of your lists.

Comment: I added it, it gave me a weird long line in the view when I run the application. any other option i can try ??